# How to dismiss magnifier from edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-12

on click of edit text in android 12 devices getting magnifier , how to dismiss this magnifier this is happening only in android 12 devices.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTzQt.png)

Comment: Are you referring to Magnifier widget or inbuilt magnifier ? Please post your code here

Comment: yes it's a inbuilt magnifier we didn't add any magnifier, on click of edit text it's showing , this is not happening below android 12 devices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.